# how to get from docx using python 3 while being accesed

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word

I'm writing a final essay in word and, in true procrastinator fashion, I want to make a program that tells me what percent progress I've made to a certain word count. Is there a way to get python 3 to extract data from a docx while it's opened? Is it as simple as paring the document every short time interval?

Comment: FYI The Status Bar in MS Word gives the word count.

Comment: It does but I wanted to see what percent I had done without having to do division by myself